# LunarG core validation layer resetting structure to zero

Tags: vulkan

I'm implementing a basic textured cube example, and have run into an interesting problem - after passing my `DescriptorWriteSet` structure to the `UpdateDescriptorSets` API call, all of the fields have been zeroed out. Any code which tries to read the fields after that gets a null pointer exception (because the DescriptorBufferInfo pointer is now null). This *only* happens when VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation is enabled, and if I disable it, the API call seems to work fine.

My sample is incomplete, so I can't say whether it works with the layer disabled, or if I have some error in *my* code. However, I have been staring at the values being passed in to this call, doing a sanity check, because I was certain *I* wasn't passing in a null pointer. Is this a bug, or is this expected behaviour?

- Windows 10
- LunarG SDK 1.0.8 (I'd like to be on 1.0.13, but that requires the newer AMD driver, which blue screens my computer)

**EDIT:**

It's not just zeroing out the structure I give it - I'm currently passing in only the first `DescriptorWriteSet` in a constant array, and it's zeroing the second as well. In fact, when I inspect the memory around the array, this layer is touching memory on either side of the array. This seems a lot more like a bug to me...

**EDIT 2:**

It turns out the problem stemmed from my code:

```
DescriptorSetLayoutBinding layout_bindings[]{
    DescriptorSetLayoutBinding()
        .Binding(0)
        .Descriptors(DescriptorType::UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1)
        .StageFlags(ShaderStageFlagBits::VERTEX),
    DescriptorSetLayoutBinding()
        .Binding(0)
        .Descriptors(DescriptorType::COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, 1)
        .StageFlags(ShaderStageFlagBits::FRAGMENT)
};
```

Both my layout bindings had the same binding index of 0. Of course, I would expect this to cause problems, but I would not expect this to cause the zeroing of structures passed in future API calls... I'm always hesitant to raise things like this as issues on Github, because more than half the time it's my fault that I'm getting the issue.

Comment: There's no such type in Vulkan called `DescriptorWriteSet`. Can you tell us what the actual Vulkan types are, perhaps with actual Vulkan code?

Comment: Sorry, that's meant to be WriteDescriptorSet. I will add the code when I get home from Uni.

Comment: What's the question? Otherwise post the legitimate issues to layer implementers https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues

Comment: BTW use updated SDK (1.0.13). ; And latest AMD version actually is 11. AFAIK you can mix and match those driver and SDK patch versions (but newest is always best, right?)

Comment: @krOoze LunarG's SDK 1.0.8 and below had a workaround for a bug in AMD's vulkan driver. Now that AMD has fixed the bug, SDK 1.0.13+ don't need to include the workaround. Unfortunately, the newer AMD driver gives me BSOD, so I'm stuck on 1.0.8 for now. This is one case where I can't mix and match driver and SDK patch versions.

Comment: So... I can delete the question, but if I want to close it, I can only vote - it still needs four other people to vote. You'd think the OP would have the option to close their own question.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson He has, by selecting prefered answer (or self-answering and selecting that, if no answer is satisfactory). The "close" is for special instances only, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation layer should not be modifying the structure pointed to by pDescriptorWrites in the vkUpdateDescriptorSets. If you think it is doing this modification of the structure passed in, please post issue, along with repo case, to https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues.

Comment: The validation layer was modifying the structure, and other memory it should not have had access to, but only because I had previously passed in bad values to the API (Specifically, I had created two `DescriptorSetLayoutBinding`s that had the same binding index). Do you think it's still worth posting it as a bug, considering it was really my fault?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yes, from your description, I think so IF you enabled all validation layers in proper order (e.g. by using `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation`). (and if that issue is not already reported of course) The point of layers is catching your bugs -- you likely wouldn't found a bug in a layer by having correct code.